# sql query to get data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

In table 1 I have

```
movie_id, movie_name
```

In table_2 I have

```
movie_id,movie_genre
```

Now I want to know the the names of movie which belongs to particular genre

What should my query look like??
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT movie_name
FROM table1
JOIN table2 USING (movie_id)
WHERE movie_genre = 'some_genre'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT movie_name
FROM table1 AS T1, table_2 AS T2
WHERE movie_genre='action' AND T1.movie_id=T2.movie_id
```